# Angular2 and Firebase (AngularFire2)

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use Angularfire2 to comunicante with Firebase. This is the code.:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item in items | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
})
class AppComponent {
  item: Observable<any>;
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.item = af.database.list('/items');
  }
}
```

The instruction `af.database.list('items')` take a few seconds to retrieve the data. So, how can I know when the data is already loaded? If I know that, I can show a "loading bar".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to subscribe for your `items` inside component like this:

```
constructor(af: AngularFire) {
  this.item = af.database.list('/items');
  this.item.subscribe(() => this.showLoader = false);
}
```

and use some field to bind for loader visibility for sure

Answer (score 0):

My bad, setTimeout will not resolve the issue completely. How about using asynchronous approach. I am not sure how to import q api in your code though.

```
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    this.item = af.database.list('/items');
    def.resolve(this.item);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the setTimeout works for fixed time no?